# Windows 10 : shellexperiencehost stealing application focus

Tags: windows-10, shell, focus, window-focus

I am a FIFA player and while playing in a match if you switch control to anywhere but the FIFA application, your game is terminated (you loose). 
I have been having problems where some background application would steal the focus (keyboard not screen) and my game would be terminated.
I decided to run a WindowsFocusLogger in the background to monitor the focus and the last time this happened I observed `shellexperiencehost` was the process to which the focus was shifted.
Why is `shellexperienncehost` stealing the focus and how can I prevent it from doing so ?

Comment: *shellexperienncehost* is connected to UWP applications, specifically, displaying them in a windowed interface.  Have you tried to enable game mode, should silence, whatever is caused your problem

Comment: It’s also not unheard of for maleware to use *shellexperienncehost*, primarily, miners.

Comment: Can I kill this process so that it isn't active altogether ? Is it a crucial process ?

Comment: Yes; it is a crucial process.